# Better way to draw this in the console

Tags: c#, ascii-art

I would like to know if there is a way to improve the code to get, in this case, doors (please don't talk about Windows Forms and better way to do Games, i'm just trying stuff out.)

Code:

```
Console.WriteLine("\t _____________\t\t" + " _____________\t\t" + " _____________");
Console.WriteLine("\t|  _________  |\t\t" + "|  _________  |\t\t" + "|  _________  |");
Console.WriteLine("\t|  |       |  |\t\t" + "|  |       |  |\t\t" + "|  |       |  |");
Console.WriteLine("\t|  |   " + input + "   |  |\t\t" + "|  |   " + (input + 1) + "   |  |\t\t" + "|  |   " + (input + 2) + "   |  |");
Console.WriteLine("\t|  |       |  |\t\t" + "|  |       |  |\t\t" + "|  |       |  |");
Console.WriteLine("\t|  |       |  |\t\t" + "|  |       |  |\t\t" + "|  |       |  |");
Console.WriteLine("\t|  |       |  |\t\t" + "|  |       |  |\t\t" + "|  |       |  |");
Console.WriteLine("\t|  |       |  |\t\t" + "|  |       |  |\t\t" + "|  |       |  |");
Console.WriteLine("\t|  |_______|  |\t\t" + "|  |_______|  |\t\t" + "|  |_______|  |");
Console.WriteLine("\t|             |\t\t" + "|             |\t\t" + "|             |");
Console.WriteLine("\t()------------|\t\t" + "()------------|\t\t" + "()------------|");
Console.WriteLine("\t|  ________   |\t\t" + "|  ________   |\t\t" + "|  ________   |");
Console.WriteLine("\t|  |       |  |\t\t" + "|  |       |  |\t\t" + "|  |       |  |");
Console.WriteLine("\t|  |       |  |\t\t" + "|  |       |  |\t\t" + "|  |       |  |");
Console.WriteLine("\t|  |       |  |\t\t" + "|  |       |  |\t\t" + "|  |       |  |");
Console.WriteLine("\t|  |       |  |\t\t" + "|  |       |  |\t\t" + "|  |       |  |");
Console.WriteLine("\t|  |_______|  |\t\t" + "|  |_______|  |\t\t" + "|  |_______|  |");
Console.WriteLine("\t|_____________|\t\t" + "|_____________|\t\t" + "|_____________|");
```

Result:

[image]

I'm asking for help to get the same result but with a better code (if possible).

Comment: If you are sticking with ASCII art, I don't know if there is much you can do about the basic form of writing long lines to the console, but you might be able to simplify it for the future if you made methods for each unique type of line, which were then called by another method to make a door of any size, number and input message, and then in the future you used that method when you needed to make doors.  Same idea for any other object.

Comment: You might try looking into `string.Format()` or the overload `Console.WriteLine(string format, params object[] arg)`. That might make the code a little bit nicer. Otherwise, agree with previous comment, probably nothing much you can do.

Comment: I will sure check on the stuff that you guys said and try something around it.

Comment: Would be +1 question (already has minimal code, expected result) if you'd specify what kind of "better" you are looking for...

Comment: I meant what @Sam achieved, a generic way to make how many doors I wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lol my attempt

```
private static string[] what = {
        "\t _____________",
        "\t|  _________  |",
        "\t|  |       |  |",
        "\t|  |   {0}   |  |",
        "\t|  |       |  |",
        "\t|  |       |  |",
        "\t|  |       |  |",
        "\t|  |       |  |",
        "\t|  |_______|  |",
        "\t|             |",
        "\t()------------|",
        "\t|  ________   |",
        "\t|  |       |  |",
        "\t|  |       |  |",
        "\t|  |       |  |",
        "\t|  |       |  |",
        "\t|  |_______|  |",
        "\t|_____________|"
        };

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    GenerateMultipleWhat(new[] { 1, 2, 3 });
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void GenerateMultipleWhat(int[] values)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < what.Length; i++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < values.Length; x++)
            Console.Write(what[i] + "{1}", values[x], (x + 1) == values.Length ? "" : "\t");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Really appreciate for this awesome reply, fit really well.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to store your ASCII art in a text file, read it when your application starts and then display its content. This will make your code much clearer, and it'll make the art easier to modify. It's what most games do, after all: instead of drawing individual pixels with code, they load their art from image and model files.

```
// At startup:
string art = File.ReadAllText("ascii_art.txt");

// whenever you need to display those doors:
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(art, input, input + 1, input + 2));
```

Example ascii_art.txt:

```
 _____   _____   _____
|     | |     | |     |
| {0} | | {1} | | {2} |
|_____| |_____| |_____|
```

Just make sure that the format specifiers match the `string.Format` arguments. Also, the format specifiers in the text file are 3 characters long, but if they are replaced by a single character then the layout will be messed up. One way to prevent that is to call `ToString().PadLeft(3)` on the `string.Format` arguments.

Comment: This is also a good and viable way, in this small project I'll keep things simple and only based on the code file. In the future this idea works better to keep like you said code much more clean. Thanks for this information ;)